# how to access an asset_path with a digest in a Rails initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I'm trying to figure out how to use asset_path in a Rails initializer in Rails 4.  I generally use the `helpers` instance on ActionController::Base to get access to url helpers outside of a view.  However, if you just call `asset_path` in the initializer it does not append the digest.  For example, this:

```
puts ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("my-image.png")
```

just outputs `my-image.png`.

The best I could come up with was this:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:after_initialize) do
    puts ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('my-image')
end
```

This works because the after_initialize hook happens after sprockets-rails loads the asset digest helpers into rails.  Is there a way to do this without waiting until after initialization?

Comment: Don't think you can but maybe you want to put your image in "/public" ?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.  I did this in a Grape API entity that is part of my Rails app.  No access to helpers.  Not sure if the below would be available pre-initialization or not.

```
Rails.application.assets["my-image"].digest_path
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I tried it but it gave me nil as the value of the asset.  Rails.application.config.assets looks a little more promising because it's paths includes all the vendor files (my file is vendorized), but I still didn't see a way to look up an asset from it.